# VSCode Find and Replace - find instances where part of search expression matches criteria and part does not

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, visual-studio-code

I want to run a regex to find instances in my code where I declare an animation duration time: e.g. `duration: 2000` and replace them with that duration plus an added variable `timeScale`, e.g. `duration: timeScale * 2000`

Some of my codebase already has this - so I want to find all instances of `duration:` that are not followed by `timeScale`.

I know I can find things that don't exist by saying: `^((?!timescale).)*$`

But how do I couple that (or something similar) with the thing that does exist (`duration:`)?

UPDATE:

I can actually run this in a regex tester:

https://regex101.com/r/vY3pY3/1

`duration: (?!timescale)`

But how do I run it in VSCode? It gives errors saying `unrecognized flag !`

[image]

Comment: Negative lookahead is `(?!timeScale)`, not `(?!=timeScale)`, you have an extra equal sign.

Comment: Update your VSCode and use `^(?!.*timescale).*duration:`. Not sure why lookahead is not accepted in your case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - It doesn't seem to like the use of `!` in this instance either. Interestingly, if I just put `^(?!.*timescale)` it doesn't throw an error, but it says it matches everything

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - your solution, coupled with setting useRipGrep to false, worked for me! If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @mheavers [Posted, see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003768/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your feedback, make sure you set `useRipGrep` to `false` and use

```
^(?!.*timescale).*duration:
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of line
- `(?!.*timescale)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match when there is `timescale` substring after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `duration:` - a `duration:` substring

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pScwJT/1).

**NOTE**: Starting with [VSCode 1.29](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_backreferences-and-lookahead-in-search), you need to [enable `search.usePCRE2` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52150634/3832970) to enable lookaheads in your regex patterns.

Answer (score 2):

*Find in files* functionality (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) seems to use a different regex flavor in contrast to *Find* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) functionality in VSC (Weird!). You may want to try the latter which supports lookaheads. [From documentations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options):

> VS Code does support regular expression searches, **however,
>   backreferences, lookaround, and multiline matches are not supported**.
>   This is because VS Code depends on the search tool [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), which,
>   while extremely fast, doesn't support these advanced regex features.

This behavior would be completely unexpected. You may also try to set:

```
"search.useRipgrep": false
```

which I think may work or may not.

Comment: Just says 'No Results'

Comment: This behavior is completely unexpected. You may also want to try `"search.useRipgrep": false` which I think may work or may not. In fact they have changed the regex engine to something less useful. What's the reason? I don't know.

Comment: Interestingly,  setting `useRipgrep` to false got rid of the error, but still returned no results.

Comment: Couldn't you just use another tool for this search / replace task?

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^(?:(?!timeScale).)*(duration: \d+)$`

Replace with: `$1 * timeScale`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2nmemn/3)

This works in Visual Studio Code 1.22.2

Comment: Well, I want to be able to match durations of any numerical value, not just 2000. Also - getting same error about the `!` if I paste that into the search window

Comment: @mheavers, I have updated the regex and demo to accept any numerical value. Also, which is the version of Visual Studio Code that you are using?

Comment: I'm using 1.24.1. Can you look at the screenshot in my question and see if it matches yours (minus the error)

Comment: @mheavers, when I do Ctrl+H (find & replace in current file), it works. however, I get the same error as yours, when I do Ctrl + Shift + H (find and replace in files).